# nativescript-contacts | How to search contacts by Number like getContactsByNumber(number)

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

Using nativescript-contacts plugin
Using nativescript 5.0 + Angular + webpack

Is there any way to get contact name based on the phone number?

The core issue is - I am want to display list of latest phone calls. It works great, but with one issue.

Let me explain with an example:
1. Call from unknown number is received at 9.00am
This shows contact name as "unknown" with the callers number in the list

2. After finishing this call by 9.10am, number is added to contacts.
3. At 10.00, call from same number is received.
4. Now in my Android App when I see call log list, I see two calls like this ->

10.00am  Jim Corbet 999988887777
9.00am   unknown    999988887777

Instead I want to show distinct phone log with contact name if it is saved.
=== Or
I will query nativescript-contacts to get contact name using the number. (This feature is not available in this plugin)

I tried using Set() with no luck.
I could not understand how to implement GROUP BY while querying, my understanding for this is limited.

Just to clarify, there is no error in program.

Here is the call log related code used:

```
var utilsModule = require("tns-core-modules/utils/utils");
public  CallLog= android.provider.CallLog;
public  Log = android.util.Log;
public  Uri = android.net.Uri;
var callUri = this.Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
var strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
var context = utilsModule.ad.getApplicationContext();
var cr=context.getContentResolver();
var curCallLogs = cr.query(callUri, null, null, null, strOrder);
//I just need latest 30 calls
for(var i=0;i<30;i++){
    curCallLogs.moveToNext();
    var strName=curCallLogs.getString(curCallLogs.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
    callobject.callerNumber=curCallLogs.getString(curCallLogs.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
}
```

Comment: When you mention call log, are you talking about your own app or the phone's call log app? "After finishing this call by 9.10am, number is added to contacts." - You mean that you are adding a new contact for that number?

Comment: Manoj, my app shows unknown for calls received prior to saving the contact, even after reading the call log after saving the contact. So I see two call details, one says unknown and other says Jim Corbet - and that for the same phone number. Thanks for the heads up!!

Meantime, Nick has posted the accurate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the native way to extract a name by a given phone number. Below you will find a basic implementation that demonstrates how to convert the java code to TypeScript. Note that I am using tns-platform-declarations to access the native APIs via TypeScript and also I am using nativescript-permissions to grant user permissions to access and read the contacts.

```
let phoneNumber = "0888111111";
let lookupUri = android.net.Uri.withAppendedPath(android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, android.net.Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
let contentResolver = application.android.context.getContentResolver();
let contactLookup = contentResolver.query(lookupUri, [android.provider.BaseColumns._ID,
    android.provider.ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.DISPLAY_NAME ], null, null, null);

if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {

    contactLookup.moveToNext();
    let name = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(android.provider.ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
    console.log(`Found name  ${name} for number ${phoneNumber}`);
} else {
    console.log("No such number in the contacts")
}
```

Also, keep in mind that the number should be parsed carefully. For example, it depends whether the contact is entered with the phone number for the local operator or with the suffix for the country + the local operator number. (e.g. 359 888111111 will not find results for 0888111111)

Full demo project demonstrating the above can be found [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/tree/master/stackoverflow/search-by-phone-number)